# mysql alias name from variable

Tags: mysql, alias, literals

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
ID  Measurement_Name
 1     Temperature
 2     Humidity
```

Table 2:

```
DateTime              *   ID  *    Value 
2017-10-20 15:52:00   *   1   *    22,3 
2017-10-20 15:51:00   *   1   *    22,1
2017-10-20 15:50:00   *   2   *    45 
2017-10-20 14:52:00   *   1   *    22,3
```

Now I select the Values from Table 2 with

```
select DateTime , Value as 'temperature' 
from Table 2 
where ID = 1;
```

Result:

```
DateTime                   *              temperature
2017-10-20 15:52:00        *              22,3 
2017-10-20 15:51:00        *              22,1 
2017-10-20 14:52:00        *              22,3
```

That works fine. But I would like to have in the Place of the literal 'temperature' the text "temperature" from table 1.
I would like to have something like

```
set @col_name := select Measurement_name from Table1 where ID = 1;`
```

I achieved this with:

```
set @statement := CONCAT("select DateTime , Value as '",@col_name,"' from Table2 where ID = 1");
Prepare statement from @statement;
execute statement;`
```

But I would prefer:

```
select DateTime , Value as @col_name 
from Table2 
where ID = 1;
```

But this generates an error (the server is only telling me, there is an error near the query.

Comment: Using the prepare statement is the only way to archieve what you want.. MySQL user variables are meant for variable data not for variable SQL like you are trying to use MySQL user variables.

Answer (score 0):

What about a JOIN ?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2,*, CONCAT(t1.Measurement_Name,t2.value)
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.ID = 1
```

Comment: When using the JOIN, I can get the measurement name as a cell in the table, but I would like to have it as the header of the table.<br/>
`DateTime * ID * Value * CONCAT (...)<br/>

2017-10-20 15:52:00 * 1 * 22,3 * temperature 1 <br/>

2017-10-20 15:51:00 * 1 * 22,1 * temperature 1 <br/>

2017-10-20 14:52:00 * 1 * 22,3 * temperature 1<br/>`